# Speisekartoffeln – Redundancy? Or indicator of something else?

Tags: meaning

I was the other day in the market and I saw the following sign:

[image: Speisekartoffeln, vorwiegend festkochend]

and my brain couldn't help but wonder: What is the point of calling a potato "Speisekartoffel"? After all, all potatoes can be eaten, no?

Is there any special connotation hidden, within this word, that differs it from normal potatoes? Or is it just a redundancy within the word, that can be totally omitted?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In this case the shop followed a German law on what must be written on a label of all food offered for sale ([Lebensmittelkennzeichnungsverordnung](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bundesrecht/lmkv/gesamt.pdf)):

> **§ 4 Verkehrsbezeichnung**
>   (1) Die Verkehrsbezeichnung eines Lebensmittels ist die in Rechtsvorschriften festgelegte Bezeichnung, bei
>   deren Fehlen
>   1.   die nach allgemeiner Verkehrsauffassung übliche Bezeichnung oder
>   2.   eine Beschreibung des Lebensmittels und erforderlichenfalls seiner Verwendung, die es dem Verbraucher ermöglicht, die Art des Lebensmittels zu erkennen und es von verwechselbaren Erzeugnissen zu
>   unterscheiden.

The key word here is the *Verkehrsbezeichnung*, i.e. the name for any food product which for potatoes again is defined by law (*Verordnung über gesetzliche Handelsklassen für Speisekartoffeln **HdlKlKartV***).

The [*Bayerische Landesanstalt für Landwirtschaft*](http://www.lfl.bayern.de/) published a guide on labelling of potatoes where it says:

> Grundlegender Bestandteil der Verkehrsbezeichnung ist der Oberbegriff
>   „Speisekartoffeln“.

So the term **Speisekartoffel** though redundant is a legal term that must be used by law when selling potatoes in Germany.

Comment: I am speechless... Amazing answer!

Comment: Germany has far too many laws and regulations... the amazing thing is that we are still able to breathe. ;)

Comment: @takkat or take a deeeeeeep breath when dealing with them ^_^

Comment: It actually makes some sense, because by using _Speisekartoffeln_ vendors assure their consumers that they are not selling them _Futter-_ or _Stärkekartoffeln_ which cannot be distinguished easily by most people, even if the correct cultivar was shown on the label. Such frauds were common in the past and illegal relabeling probably still happens. _Saatkartoffeln_ are sometimes sold for cooking as _Drillinge_, but they’re clearly smaller – actually the ones sold at high prices in supermarkets are often too small for seeding, thus would otherwise be considered B or C class, i.e. animal feed.

Comment: @Takkat As long as they aren't draconian or insensible they aren't necessarily bad I guess.

Answer (score 20):

*Speisekartoffeln* is the official term to distinguish potatoes intended for human consumption from *Futterkartoffeln* (for animal feed), *Saatkartoffeln* (seedlings) and *Stärkekartoffeln* (industrial raw material, for paper manufacturing and as a glue base product).

Obviously, all of those are potatoes, and one wouldn't really expect to see anything but *Speisekartoffeln* in a supermarket. So I go with you it is some kind of marketing nonsense.

Comment: In that case, the only difference is the way it is "used"? A "speisekartoffeln" can become any other kind of *kartoffeln*?

Comment: @Dbugger not necessarily. Stärkekartoffeln have more starch (Stärke) in them. And nowadays, many companies, that produce seedlings design them that their offspring can't be used for seeding. so a Speisekartoffel could come from a Saatkartoffel but couldn't be used as one.

Comment: That is interesting. It may be BS to put it in the market sign, but I guess there are differences and connotations inside the word. Thanks for expanding the answer.

Comment: Was ist mit Früh- und Süßkartoffeln?

Comment: @userunknown Frühkartoffeln are "early potatoes" - the new and first potatoes in the year. Often with a fine taste and a very thin skin. [Süßkartoffeln](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Süßkartoffel) are a fruit on its own - the main thing they share with potatoes is the name ;)

Comment: @user unknown Früh- und Süsskartoffeln *are not* legally required *Lebensmittelkennzeichnungen* (see Takkat's answer below) while the three mentioned ones are.

Comment: Danke, danke. Und nicht zu vergessen edle, original, Lübecker Marzipankartoffeln.

Comment: @user unknown. Nee, die auch nicht ;)

Comment: Wegen des Nicotingehalts der Schalen werden Kartoffeln übrigens auch angebaut - allerdings dann nicht im Supermarkt vertrieben.